# Optimizing Matrix class with less calls to new

Tags: c#, performance, matrix

I'm designing a Matrix class and I feel like what I've come up with requires too many calls to `new`.  I know it's possible that caring about this is premature, but I already know I need this code to be fast, so I'd like to think about streamlining it now.

Here's a test to show how I intend to use the API:

```csharp
[Fact]
public void TranslateFluentAPI()
{
    Matrix4 t = Matrix4.Identity().Translate(5, -3, 2);
    Point p = new Point(-3, 4, 5);
    Assert.True(t * p == new Point(2, 1, 7));

    // Same, but use the parameterless c'tor, which is equivalent to
    // calling Identity();
    Matrix4 t2 = new Matrix4().Translate(5, -3, 2);
    Assert.True(t2 * p == new Point(2, 1, 7));
}
```

And my code stripped down to the relevant parts (only missing additional matrix math and similar subclasses for Matrix3, Matrix2)

```csharp
using System;
using static System.Math;

public abstract class Matrix : IEquatable<Matrix>
{
    // 2D array that stores Matrix data.
    protected double[,] data;

    // Concrete Matrix classes must override a size.
    abstract protected int size { get; }

    public Matrix(double[,] data)
    {
        if (data.GetLength(0) != size || data.GetLength(1) != size) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"The provided 2D array needs to have a length of {size} "+
                "in both dimensions.");
        }
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Matrix()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    // Square bracket getter/setter
    public double this[int x, int y] {
        get { return this.data[x, y]; }
        set { this.data[x, y] = value; }
    }

    #region Equality
    public bool Equals(Matrix other)
    {
        if (size != other.size) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"Cannot compare a matrix of size {other.size} to a matrix"+
                $"of size {size}.");
        }

        double epsilon = 0.00001;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
                if (! (Abs(this[x, y] - other[x, y]) < epsilon)) {
                    // One element is not equal, so matrices are not equal.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // All elements were equal
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Matrix);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return data.GetHashCode();
    }
    
    public static bool operator ==(Matrix obj1, Matrix obj2)
    {
        return obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Matrix obj1, Matrix obj2)
    {
        return ! obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }
    #endregion
}

public class Matrix4 : Matrix
{
    protected override int size => 4;

    public Matrix4(double[,] data) : base(data)
    {
        // Do nothing, calling base class.
    }

    public Matrix4() : base()
    {
        data = Matrix4.Identity().data;
    }

    public static implicit operator Matrix4(double[,] m) => new Matrix4(m);

    public static Matrix4 Identity()
    {
        return new Matrix4(new double[,] {
            {1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1},
        });
    }

    public static Matrix4 operator *(Matrix4 a, Matrix4 b)
    {
        double[,] result = new double[4, 4];

        for (int x = 0; x < a.size; x += 1) {
            for (int y = 0; y < a.size; y += 1) {
                result[x, y] =
                    a[x, 0] * b[0, y] +
                    a[x, 1] * b[1, y] +
                    a[x, 2] * b[2, y] +
                    a[x, 3] * b[3, y];
            }
        }

        return new Matrix4(result);
    }

    public Matrix4 Translate(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        Matrix4 t = Matrix4.Identity();
        t[0, 3] = x;
        t[1, 3] = y;
        t[2, 3] = z;
        this.data = (t * this).data;
        return this;
    }
}
```

So adding up calls to new:

```csharp
// Using the static Identity method:
Matrix4 t = Matrix4.Identity().Translate(5, -3, 2);
// This is 5 calls to new.

// As a convenience I have the parameterless c'tor to return the identity,
// so that you can do this:
Matrix4 t = new Matrix4().Translate(5, -3, 2);
// This is 6 calls to new.
```

Premature optimization aside, at the very least **I wish I could make the second form not cost more than the first**, because it feels like a much more intuitive way to use the API.

Comment: @Heslacher I'm not sure what you think you're missing.  I assure you the implementation of IEquatable, ToString, and a few operators are not at all relevant this question about c'tors.  I probably should have posted to SO but they usually downvote for the question being too broad ...

Comment: Well at least the implementation of the `*` operator is needed.

Comment: @Heslacher ah sure thing, just updated. I believe that code is entirely self-contained now.

Comment: Ok, for me it seems sufficient code now. If you don't receive a review I will check it out on monday.

Answer (score 3):

First let's target your main concern regarding `Matrix4 t = new Matrix4().Translate(5, -3, 2);` using the same number of ctor calls as `Matrix4 t = Matrix4.Identity().Translate(5, -3, 2);`.

This can be easily achieved by extracting the `double[,]` out of `Identity()` like so

```
private static readonly double[,] identityData = new double[,] {
    {1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1},
};
public static Matrix4 Identity()
{
    return new Matrix4(identityData);
}
```

now the call to the parameterless ctor will look like so

```
public Matrix4() : base()
{
    data = identityData;
}
```

---

In the `Translate()` method you are only interested in the `data` of the multiplied matrixes. You **could** extract the multiplication into a separate `Multiply()` method which would be called by the `Translate()` method and in the `*` operator like so

```
public static Matrix4 operator *(Matrix4 a, Matrix4 b)
{
    return new Matrix4(Multiply(a.data, b.data));

}
private static double[,] Multiply(double[,] a, double[,] b)
{
    int size = a.GetLength(0);
    double[,] result = new double[size, size];

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1)
        {
            result[x, y] =
                a[x, 0] * b[0, y] +
                a[x, 1] * b[1, y] +
                a[x, 2] * b[2, y] +
                a[x, 3] * b[3, y];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public Matrix4 Translate(double x, double y, double z)
{
    Matrix4 t = Matrix4.Identity();
    t[0, 3] = x;
    t[1, 3] = y;
    t[2, 3] = z;
    this.data = Multiply(t.data, this.data);
    return this;
}
```

It is only a matter of taste, but I prefer to use e.g `x++` over `x +=1`.

---

You **could** save one more call to the ctor by just using the `identityData` inside the `Translate()` method like so

```
public Matrix4 Translate(double x, double y, double z)
{
    double[,] t = identityData;
    t[0, 3] = x;
    t[1, 3] = y;
    t[2, 3] = z;
    this.data = Multiply(t, this.data);
    return this;
}
```

Summing up will lead to

```
public class Matrix4 : Matrix
{
    protected override int size => 4;

    public Matrix4(double[,] data) : base(data)
    { }  // Do nothing, calling base class.


    public Matrix4() : base()
    {
        data = identityData;
    }

    public static implicit operator Matrix4(double[,] m) => new Matrix4(m);

    private static readonly double[,] identityData = new double[,] {
        {1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1},
    };
    public static Matrix4 Identity()
    {
        return new Matrix4(identityData);
    }

    public static Matrix4 operator *(Matrix4 a, Matrix4 b)
    {
        return new Matrix4(Multiply(a.data, b.data));

    }
    private static double[,] Multiply(double[,] a, double[,] b)
    {
        int size = a.GetLength(0);
        double[,] result = new double[size, size];

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1)
            {
                result[x, y] =
                    a[x, 0] * b[0, y] +
                    a[x, 1] * b[1, y] +
                    a[x, 2] * b[2, y] +
                    a[x, 3] * b[3, y];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Matrix4 Translate(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double[,] t = identityData;
        t[0, 3] = x;
        t[1, 3] = y;
        t[2, 3] = z;
        this.data = Multiply(t, this.data);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now `Matrix4 t = Matrix4.Identity().Translate(5, -3, 2);` and `Matrix4 t = new Matrix4().Translate(5, -3, 2);` only call the ctor once. **You** need to decide if the code is still readable and maintainable.

---

Base class

The `Equals(Matrix)` should check for `null` for the passed `Matrix other`. Its better to return `false` if `other == null` than to get a `NullReferenceException`.

```
public bool Equals(Matrix other)
{
    if (other == null) { return false; }

    if (size != other.size)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"Cannot compare a matrix of size {other.size} to a matrix" +
            $"of size {size}.");
    }

    double epsilon = 0.00001;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1)
        {
            if (!(Abs(this[x, y] - other[x, y]) < epsilon))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Both, the `==` and `!=` operator should check for `null` as well like so

```
public static bool operator ==(Matrix obj1, Matrix obj2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)) { return true; }
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, null)) { return false; }
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj2, null)) { return false; }

    return obj1.Equals(obj2);
}

public static bool operator !=(Matrix obj1, Matrix obj2)
{
    return !(obj1 == obj2);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you @heslacher, I was just working out the need to compare to null, and your equality implementation totally makes sense!  Something is funky about the static identityData solution though.  See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k9aVHW
I think that's because in the Matrix4 parameterless c'tor you assign `data` to `identityData` which becomes a reference.  Then elsewhere, any client that mutates its copy of an identity matrix actually changes the underlying readonly(!) static data.  Seems like I want to make a copy of `identityData`, but I'm back to needing another `new` for that ...